# Gcloud CLI using what APIs

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I've been thinking that how the `gcloud` work for a long time.

Because I saw a bunch of python files in `./google-cloud-sdk` after I installed the [Google CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#installation_instructions) and used the tree command to see what files in the there.

Therefore I guess If I execute `gcloud compute instance list`. This command will call this [API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list) to get the list of instances.

If it is true, I would like to know how to use `gcloud` internally to reach Google APIs.

Comment: To what do you refer as "internally"

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the document:

> Use `private.googleapis.com` to access Google APIs and services by using
> a set of IP addresses only routable from within Google Cloud.

If you need to restrict users to just the Google APIs and services that support VPC Service Controls, use `restricted.googleapis.com`.

Also check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options) for more information.